# I want to pass in 1 inplace of 4 and that result set should return in reverse order

Tags: mysql

I need help with a query

```
SELECT  CONVERT(@r, DECIMAL) AS _id,
         (
         SELECT  @r := parentid
         FROM    People
         WHERE   peopleid = _id
         ) AS ParentID,
         @l := @l + 1 AS Level
FROM    (
         SELECT  @r := 4,
                 @l := 0,
                 @cl := 0
         ) vars,
         People h
WHERE    @r  0
```

And it returns

```
_id    ParentID   Level
--------------------------
 4       3        1
 3       1        2
 1       0        3
```

and my table name is "People" and records are-

```
PeopleID             LName           FName             ParentID
   1                  ABC             XYZ                0
   2                  PQR             JKL                1
   3                  SAM             QWE                1
   4                  SCOTT           JIMMY              3
```

**Que:- It is basically correct but only difference is instead of passing in 4(i.e. no of rows) I want to pass in 1 (i.e. starting point) and that result set should return in reverse order.

how it will be done? should i change something in query?**

Thanks,
Kishor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT _id, ParentID, Level
FROM (
 SELECT  CONVERT(@r, DECIMAL) AS _id,
         (
         SELECT  @r := parentid
         FROM    People
         WHERE   peopleid = _id
         ) AS ParentID,
         @l := @l + 1 AS Level
 FROM    (
         SELECT  @r := 4,
                 @l := 0,
                 @cl := 0
         ) vars,
         People h
 WHERE    @r  0
) as InitialQ
ORDER BY Level Desc
```

Comment: thanks for answering, but this query returns same output, instead of passing @r := 4 i have to pass @r := 1 and the result set should return same output but in reverse order.